# Why Lucene does not working when search on hierarchy folders with multiple words?

Tags: c#, .net, lucene, lucene.net

I am using Lucene to search files inside of the folders hierarchy below. The default root folder is always "Documents". The "Documents" folder also contains files. It is working when all of my folders name is whole word, however when folder name is multiple words it didn't work as expected.

```
Sample Folder Hierarchy

Documents
   Folder One
      Folder Two and Three
   Folder Four and Five
      Folder Six and Seven
           Folder Eight
```

I tried the query below to search files in the specific folder hierarchy. However it didn't work.

```
Sample Query
    +(kw-extension:(doc docx xls xlsx ppt pptx txt pdf DOC DOCX XLS XLSX PPT PPTX TXT PDF)) +(kw-folderName:(*documents/Folder Four and Five/Folder Six and Seven/))
```

What is missing on my query?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you indexed the information and what analyze and filters you used.  One thing you might want to look into is shingles.  Shingles is an approach to index multiple words together. [Here](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/4.8.0-beta00016/api/analysis-common/Lucene.Net.Analysis.Shingle.html) is some info on shingles to get you started.